# Yii CLinkPager change link page

Tags: php, yii

In my project I want to change the link url because it does not look good.
The link is as example below:

- http://www.example.com/product?Product[pagesize]=24&page=2
- http://www.example.com/product?Product[brand_id][]=3

so I want to the url like this

- http://www.example.com/product?pagesize=24&page=2
- http://www.example.com/product?brd[]=3

I use Yii framewrok, so is it possible to change it?
Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, this format is really not useful. Why this format?

Comment: Because I use it with model(Product) so when I navigate it the url change like I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why u use difficult url instead of dataprovider of yii for paging. here is code:

controller:

```
 $pageSize=5; 
         $news = News::model()->findAll(); //returns AR objects
         $count = count($news);

         $dataProvider= new CArrayDataProvider($news, array(
               'sort'=>array('attributes'=>array('title')),   //you can sort here if objects not sorted
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>$pageSize),
          ));

        $models = $dataProvider->getData();          

         $this->render('index', array(
                    'models' => $models,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 
                    'itemCount' => $count,
          ));
```

on view:

```
<?php
  $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
                'pages'=>$dataProvider->pagination,
                ));
    ?>
```

Comment: you're welcome, you should click on check button for resolve this problem